# Is this code outdated? getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()

Tags: android, path, filepath

Why this code is my white line drawing problem What is the problem
Is there a way to replace it?

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
```

Exactly this line of code is drawn by the white line method
**`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment) --> <s>**Deprecated**</s> in API level 29

> To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage
>   devices is deprecated. When an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the
>   path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to
>   apps. Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external
>   storage by migrating to alternatives such as
>   [**`Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), MediaStore, or
>   Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

```
void createExternalStoragePrivateFile() {
    // Create a path where we will place our private file on external
    // storage.
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "DemoFile.jpg");

    try {
        // Very simple code to copy a picture from the application's
        // resource into the external file.  Note that this code does
        // no error checking, and assumes the picture is small (does not
        // try to copy it in chunks).  Note that if external storage is
        // not currently mounted this will silently fail.
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.balloons);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data);
        os.write(data);
        is.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
        // not currently mounted.
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
    }
}
```